# XQuery : compute distance between author

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to compute the distance between authors of books. 
Authors that have published a book together have distance 1. 
Moreover, if a and b have not published a book together but they have both published together with c, then the distance between a and b is 2.

Here is an XML file for example :

```
<root>
     <book title="book1">
          <author> Thibaut </author>
          <author> Luc </author>
     </book>
     <book title="book2">
          <author> Luc </author>
          <author> Jay </author>
     </book>
     <book title="book3">
          <author> Jay </author>
          <author> Henry </author>
     </book>
</root>
```

#### According to this XML, the distance between author "Thibaut" and others are the following :

- Thibaut and Luc distance of 1 (because they have publisher book1 together .. Thibaut -> Luc)
- Thibaut and Jay distance of 2 (because Thibaut/Luc have publisher together, and Luc/Jay have publisher together, so distance between Thibaut and Jay is 2 ... Thibaut -> Luc -> Jay)
- Thibaut and Henry distance of 3 (because Thibaut -> Luc -> Jay -> Henry)
- My XML example is short, but of couse distance can go higher

For every author X in my XML file, I need to compute the distance with all others authors y (x != y, so not same author)
Does anabody know how to code this in XQUery ? Or have ideas for the algorithm ?

Any help appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: You XML is not well-formed. Are you sure this is the full input? What did you try?

Comment: I know, but this is just a supporting example for my explanation. However, I have corrected my example to add a racine.

Comment: The root node can be important for the query, and omitting such information will just lead to confusion and endless discussions. Always make sure to have _reproducible_ problem statements. Also: without showing any effort, what you tried and a clear problem statement apart from "please code this for me", don't expect anybody to put effort in an answer; especially not for textbook/class exercises. Have a look at [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I understand your point of view on the involvement of the topic's writer, but I'm stuck and have no ideas on how to perform this distance computation. I'm not especially looking for a complete solution,  that's why I stated " Or have ideas for the algorithm ?". I'm working on it, and if I come up with something I'll update my original post.

Comment: Well, this is a shortest-path problem. The canonical solution would be to implement the Dijkstra algorithm. For reasonable small input, you might also be fine with breath-first-search, which can be implemented using a recursive function traversing the "graph" step for step; depth-first-search would be even slower, but is easier to implement using recursive functions.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I'm not sure how to create a graph in Xquery. I will search for this. Basic idea is to create a graph that has all authors as nodes, with an edge between author a and author b iff a and b have written a publication together. And the distance between two authors a
and b is the shortest path. Dijkstra has defenitely the lowest complexity. My input is huge, 800MO xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow represent your graph in memory, such that you can run a shortest-path algorithm on it. In fact your above document could be seen as a graph representation, but it may be redundant (the same pair of authors may have published multiple books together).

Better representations of graphs can be (among others) adjacency lists, adjacency matrices, or incident matrices. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29

Since your graph is probably sparse, you should choose adjacency lists. An adjacency list is of the form Node -> List[Node], that means it maps each node to the list of its adjacent nodes. In Java, you would chose a Map (e.g. HashMap) to store this in memory. For running your graph algorithm the data structure should have low lookup time. XQuery does not have maps, but you can create xml fragments as values for a variable. This is an example:

```
let $a := 
  <map>
    <author>
        <name>Luc</name>
        <coauthors>
          <name>Thibault</name>
        </coauthors>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Jay</name>
      <coauthors>
        <name>Henry</name>
        <name>Luc</name>
      </coauthors>
      ...
    </author>
  </map>
```

Note that this is not the complete graph representation, but just a subset of the edges. You need to define a subprogram that computes this intermediate result from your input document. Then you can define a utility function that gives you the immediately adjacent authors for a given author name using this intermediate result. Based on that you can implement the shortest path algorithm.

Note that the above graph representation will not be efficient for looking up adjacent nodes, and I believe it is hard to code an efficient lookup function for adjacent nodes. The lookup function mentioned above will need to traverse the entire intermediate result in the worst case (if you look up the adjacent nodes for the last author). If you are concerned about runtime, I would recommend using your general purpose programming language of choice (e.g. Java). If the graph representation does not fit in memory, use some kind of on disk index structure (provided e.g. by a relational database).

Comment: sorry for my late reply, but thanks for these great informations. I will try your idea !